# How to find svn directory from local java project programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I wonder that how to find related svn repository directory from existed local java project instead of svn commands ?
To be clear , my project is already checked out and i have .svn file for each folder. Here is an image to show clearly: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vg6fhx190ae60fy/Capture.PNG

Is there any proper  and efficient class to get svn directory path? I tried some classes like [RepositoryProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/team/core/RepositoryProvider.html), SVNTeamProvider, SVNClientManager but I do not clear up.

Comment: You wanna do it programmatically, isn't it?

Comment: What would the command line command be which would produce the output you seek?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but maybe have a look at SVNKit or JavaHL (both are SVN Connectors for Eclipse SVN tooling).

Comment: Please note that OP wants to do this in Java code, not using a third party tool.